# PromiseKit how to return "when(resolved)" as a promise?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, promise, promisekit

I have a series of functions that look like this:

```
func getA() -> Promise<Void> {
  // code
}

func getB() -> Promise<Void> {
  // code
}

func getC() -> Promise<Void> {
  // code
}
```

I want to return a Promise when all of these are finished. Here's what I tried:

```
func getStuff() -> Promise<[Result<Void>]> {
  return when(resolved: [getA(), getB(), getC()])
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error: `'Result' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42881540/3478010) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getStuff() -> Promise<[PromiseKit.Result<Void>]> {
    return when(resolved: [getA(), getB(), getC()])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things named `Result` in your code and you need to tell Swift that `Result` in this case refers to PromiseKit.Result or to use `Resolution` assuming it's not taken in the namespace and you don't care about the related ErrorConsumptionToken.

```
func getStuff() -> Promise<[Resolution<Void>]> {
  return when(resolved: [getA(), getB(), getC()])
}
```